# @AcitiveProfiles works for ANY suffix except "test" for loading application-test.yml

Tags: junit, applicationcontext, spring-profiles

It used to work fine with @ActiveProfiles("test") and @SpringBootTest(...) in JUnit4.
One day, it suddenly fail to load the application-test.yml, thus fail to load the ApplicationContext.

But if I change the filename from "application-test.yml" to "application-tests.yml" or "application-anySuffix.yml", and use @ActiveProfiles("anySuffix"), it works fine again.

It seems @ActiveProfiles works for any suffix and can load ApplicationContext, except the suffix "test", why would this weird thing happen?

I guess it's related to my IntelliJ settings, since when I clone other correct projects, same things happens in my IntelliJ.

Dose anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: 1. Though the "anySuffix" can load ApplicationContext and load `@Value` without NullPointerException, but the tests seems abnormal and returns 302 instead of 200.   
      
2. It works fine with application-test.yml when gradlew.bat build, only in IntelliJ it will fail to load ApplicationContext because it cannot load `@Value`.       
  
3. The resources folder already marked as "test resources".        

4. Have tried invalidate cache and restart         

5. Tried edit configuration -> environment variables -> SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test

Comment: - 6. Tried adding `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`
- 7. Tried to use `@SpringBootTest(properties="spring.profiles.active=test")`

- Actually, the spring.profiles.active is indeed "test", but `@Value` is still loaded from application.yml instead of application-test.yml